# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in cv2.matchTemplate()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am currently working on a project where the goal is to recognize a "symbol" from a camera stream. To do this I am using the `cv2.matchTemplate()` function. I am using RasPi 3B and the RasPi camera module V2 to get the video. I have encountered an error and I thought it was caused by an incorrect path to the template, but after checking it I've found out that the path correct.

Here are the prints of both the video shape and template shape

```
frame.shape= [480,640,3]

t0.shape= [300,300,3] (I will make this one smaller, probably to like [30,30,3])
```

My main piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import argparse
import imutils
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-t0", "--template0", required = True, help = "Cesta k 
templatu pro cmd0")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

t0 = cv2.imread(args["template0"])
w, h,_ = t0.shape[::-1]

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

time.sleep(0.1)

for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", 
use_video_port=True):
    frame = f.array

    print(frame.shape)
    print(t0.shape)

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 300)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray, t0, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) #the error throwing line
    treshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where(res >= treshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
       cv2.rectangle(frame, pt, (pt[0]+w, pt[1]+h), (0,255,0), 2)    

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
```

And the error message I am getting:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2) in matchTemplate, file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 1102
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmplRec_fin1.py", line 43, in <module>
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray, t0, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:1102: error: (-215) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function matchTemplate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

It was exactly what caused the problem and I honestly don't understand how I even made such a dumb mistake. Hopefully it will help someone in the future.

In short: What was causing the problem for me was that I tried matching a grayscale video stream to an rgb template, that doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the depth of the image or it's channels. Make sure you compare grayscale to grayscale.

Comment: Note: a discrepancy in data type between image and template results in the same assertion error (e.g. uint8 vs float32)